# VPN connection in Windows 10 disappeared, but still exists somewhere

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have a VPN connection on my Windows 10 laptop and have used it for years, but from one moment to the next it disappeared. When I open up the pane with all connections (Wifi and VPN) in the bottom right corner it takes clearly more time as usual to load. And when the connections appears, the VPN is missing.

When I open the VPN overview from the Windows Settings there are no VPN's shown. When I try to add a VPN with the same name it doesn't work, because the name already exists. Creating a VPN with a new name doesn't work either, cause after choosing 'Save', nothing happens.

Opening up the Wi-fi settings also takes a lot of time.

Hopefully someone knows a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

While trying to debug the issue I've checked for Windows updates, but no updates available. After posting the question above I was going to shut my computer down, and Windows showed the option to 'shutdown and install updates'. Did that and reboot my laptop, everything was back to normal.